# Cassandra: Unusual High CPU Util at same moment (everyday)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, bigdata, database, nosql

We are using 3-nodes Cassandra Cluster in production from 4-5 months, We haven't faced any major issue, however, every day at 2200 hours (UTC), we see a spike in CPU Utilization (see the attached graph).

I have confirmed there is no major load from our end at that time. Also, most of the time CPU Util is < 1%, (< 15% while querying and few jobs). We take snapshots at a different time, nowhere close to 2200 hours.

There is nothing unusual in `system.log` and `debug.log`.

One more important thing is, it happens only for one node. All of them reache their highest CPU Util, but one of the node is always thrice as much as others.

(Orange colors are first node. All the peaks are at 2200 hours)

Graph for all 3 nodes.
[image]

Graph for 2 nodes, except first one (orange). As per @PhillipBlum asked.
[image]

Comment: Can you make a screenshout without the orange (first node)? I think it could be the compaction job. Huge random data income. Can you talk a bit about the model on your nodes? How the data are sorted etc.

Comment: Hey Philipp, I have added another screenshot in question description.

Comment: Also, there is no huge data flow at that moment, we have verified it for all days.

Comment: Data Models: 
We have multiple tables on a single keyspace. 
1. Time series table: Partition Key - today's date, Clustering Key - TimeUUID of today's date, 1 index for event_name and 4th column is payload in JSON format.
2. Other tables have partition key based on some ID and clustering key is timestamps. All those 7-8 tables have atleast 2-3 indices.

Comment: I have seen this is lots of deployments - in nearly every case there is a system process or cron job doing something at 10. This sometimes is a backup or some audit process but you can be 99% sure thats whats causing this. Some enterprises have jobs that log on to servers to run the processes so they may not show up on the actual box. Check with your admin team.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PatrickCallaghan. I'm completely taking care of the cluster and I am the admin as well. There is nothing running at that moment. I am taking snapshot at a totally different time.